# Error response from daemon - docker manjaro

Tags: docker, daemon, manjaro

I'm having this problem in docker using manjaro (Kernel: Linux 5.11.10-1-MANJARO)

```
$ docker pull hello-world
```

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for bitty-buddy.coxauto-dzcp1-user-control-plane.com, not registry-1.docker.io

This is my daemon.json

"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]

I have tried change to "1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1", but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need to [set up an HTTPS proxy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#running-a-docker-daemon-behind-an-https_proxy) to reach sites outside your corporate network?

Answer (score -1):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32023104/15630397) will solve your problem.

> I had the same problem this morning and the following fixed it for me:

```
$ docker-machine restart default      # Restart the environment
$ eval $(docker-machine env default)  # Refresh your environment settings
```

> It appears that this is due to the Docker virtual machine getting itself into a strange state.

Next create an account at [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/) and login docker in console:

```
docker login
```

Now you can pull images from hub.